# Wait for function is done before triggering the next one Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that triggers once a file is uploaded to S3. There's a slight possibility that two files might be uploaded at the same time. The thing is, I don't want the lambda function running both files at the same time. I want one file to go first and then another. Is this possible?

Comment: May want to consider using SQS to store file name (endpoint) and have the lambada function process the  queue one at a time another option to what @haggbart has outline in his answer.

Comment: Can you tell us more about _why_ you don't want them processed at the same time? Does the function read the output from an earlier execution?